# I have an issue with access database inserting execution time

Tags: c#, ms-access

When I try to insert something in access database and make query to retrieve last inserted row it gives me the before last inserted.

It indicates that the query I used to retrieve last row couldn't read (last inserted) yet, which indicates there is a problem in Insertion execution time ...

Here is my code:

```
 tst t = new tst() {  txt="test"};
 t.Insert();
 var res = DataAccess.GetSqlValue("select * from tst where id=(select max(id) from tst)", EgxDataType.Msaccess);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the definition of your `Insert` method?

Comment: Insert method form insert sql statement then passes parameters to sql statement and finally execute non query using OleDbCommand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tst WHERE id=(SELECT max(id+1) FROM tst)
```

Comment: Thank's MiHawk , but it is not a solution for mentioned problem , and if it works for one time it will not work for the next times because it debendes on insertion execution time  .

Answer (score 0):

Refer this msdn approach [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or

in more you can modify your Insert process.

```
Insert Into Table_1(Name)
    OutPut Inserted.Id,Inserted.Name
values('Sandeep')
```

Now if you run `select * from Inserted` you will get latest record as table which is inserted last.

and use ExecuteReader at OleDBCommand to receive result.

Comment: It is not my issue to retrieve records as table or not , further than it will affect performance badly